# Attempt to index field 'parent' (a nil value)

Tags: android, iphone, indexing, lua

I'm having some troubles when I try to reload a scene.

In my program, users are able to draw a line with their finger (it's an iOS/Android app), and it works pretty good, but, when I try to reload the scene, the console returns

"Attempt to index field 'parent' (a nil value)"

at line 39

The code I've used to perform the "drawline" and the reload (replay in this case) features is

```
local lines = {}
local lineGroup = display.newGroup()
local prevX,prevY
local isDrawing = true
local i = 1


local function distanceBetween(x1, y1, x2, y2)
local dist_x = x2 - x1
local dist_y = y2 - y1
local distanceBetween = math.sqrt((dist_x*dist_x) + (dist_y*dist_y))
return distanceBetween
end



local function drawLine(e)
if(e.phase == "began") then

    for i = #lines, 1, -1 do
  if (lines[i]) then
   lines[i].parent:remove(lines[i])
   lines[i] = nil
  end
end
lines = {}
line_number = 100


    prevX = e.x
    prevY = e.y
    isDrawing = true


elseif(e.phase == "moved") then
    local distance = distanceBetween(prevX, prevY, e.x, e.y)
    if(isDrawing and distance < 100) then
        if(lines[i]) then lineGroup:remove(i) end
        lines[i] = display.newLine(prevX, prevY, e.x, e.y)
        lines[i]:setColor(255, 255, 0)
        lines[i].width = 3
        lines[i].myName = "lines"


if(lines[i].y < 400) then
for i = #lines, 1, -1 do
  if (lines[i]) then
   lines[i].parent:remove(lines[i])
   lines[i] = nil
  end
end
end

        local dist_x = e.x - prevX
        local dist_y = e.y - prevY
        physics.addBody(lines[i], "static", 
        { density = 1, friction = 0.5, 
     bounce =  -0.8, shape = {0, 0, dist_x, dist_y,        0, 0} } )
        lineGroup:insert(lines[i])
    end


elseif(e.phase == "ended") then
    isDrawing = true
end

return lineGroup
end


Runtime:addEventListener("touch",drawLine)
```

where line 39 is `lines[i].parent:remove(lines[i])`

Any suggestions? Thanks! :)

******HERE'S HOW I RESTART MY GAME*************************

```
--REPLAY

 local replayBTN = display.newImage("immagini/pause.png")

 replayBTN.alpha = 1
 replayBTN.x = _W/2 
 replayBTN.y = _H/2 

 localGroup:insert( replayBTN)

 function replay(event)
director:changeScene("game")
 return true
 end

 replayBTN:addEventListener("touch", replay)
```

Comment: I don't see where you assign `parent` any value. Why would it not be `nil`? You can inspect the value of `lines[i]` before it hits line 39.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can just do an additional check:

```
  if (lines[i]) then
      if (lines[i].parent) then
         lines[i].parent:remove(lines[i])
      end
      lines[i] = nil
  end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did what you told me, but now I get "attempt to call method 'insert' (a nil value)" on line 78, where line 78 is

lineGroup:insert(lines[i])
What can I do? Thanks again.

Comment: How are you reloading your game? Addressing your question, do another check for existence: if(lineGroup) then lineGroup:insert(lines[i]) end

Comment: Nevermind, disregard my previous comment, since lineGroup exists otherwise it wouldn't have that error. Instead, you might be restarting your game and not initializing lineGroup = display.newGroup() again before you use it.

Comment: Thanks again, sorry but I'm a newbie to lua, how can I restart my game and not initialize lineGroup?

Comment: Well, how are you restarting your game? Please post your code in the original question.

Comment: Done, check out the original question